# Octal Numbers - what I might be missing to check if the input number recieved is of an Octal Format or Not?

Tags: php, octal

Just learnt the basics of converting a Decimal Number to an Octal Number. Now for the reverse, I seem to have got the fact that any number whose last digit ending is either 8 or 9, cannot be an octal number.
**But, is there anything else that I would need to check or do to see if an input number is an Octal Number or not (apart from checking 8 or 9 in the last digit)?.** - [basically, enquiring if I am missing a certain process]

Below is my code in PHP:

```
<?php 

$iOctal = 1423;
echo "What is the Decimal Value of the octal number $iOctal?"."<br/>";

$rg_Decimal = str_split($iOctal);
//print_r($rg_Decimal);

if (end($rg_Decimal) == 8 || end($rg_Decimal) == 9){
    echo "<b>Error:- </b>Unable to process your request as the input number format is not of the Octal Number Format. Please try again...";
}

if ($iOctal < 8 && $iOctal >= 0){
    echo "The Decimal Value of the octal number $iOctal is $iOctal.";
}
else{

    $iE = count($rg_Decimal);
    --$iE;
    $iDecimal = 0;

    for ($iA = 0; $iA < sizeof($rg_Decimal); ++$iA){

        $iDecimal += $rg_Decimal[$iA] * bcpow(8,$iE);
        --$iE;
    }
    echo "The Decimal Value of the octal number $iOctal is <b>$iDecimal</b>";
}
```

?>

It just so happened that during the testing, I had used an online resource. When I had given a particular number, it said that the number format was not octal. But the number did not have an 8 or 9 ending.
Looking forward to your kind support.

Comment: Yeah, 142876... could you please explain why this number may not be an octal number... what am I missing to understand here. The last digit is not 8 or 9. Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin function `octdect($number)` from php.
An example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.octdec.php , with the same question:

```
<?php

function is_octal($x) {
    return decoct(octdec($x)) == $x;
}

echo is_octal(077); // true
echo is_octal(195); // false

?>
```

Comment: Hi Mark Van Herpen, its just that I am learning to code and prefer not to use any prebuilt function. I am missing something somewhere, I dont know what it is.... Could you please help me understand with my existing program Mark?